# Why is my Jest code coverage report invalid?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, code-coverage

When I generate a Jest code coverage report for my Vue 2.7.X app, the lines shown as covered/uncovered in the report don't make any sense:

[image]

The red sections in this report should indicate code that's not covered (executed) by the test suite, but obviously it makes no sense to show comments (lines 290, 291) as uncovered, or to show (part of) line 298 as uncovered when the lines before and after are covered.

I guess what's happening is that the lines which Jest detects as uncovered are not being correctly mapped back to the source code, so there may be a problem with the Babel transpilation.

I generate the code coverage report with `yarn jest --coverage` and the application source code is written in JavaScript (rather than TypeScript).

some of the dependencies from `package.json` which may be relevant to the problem are shown below:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.3.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "29.2.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue2": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
    "http-proxy": "^1.18.1",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "sass-lint": "^1.13.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.22.12",
    "vite": "^4.0.1",
    "vite-plugin-rewrite-all": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14"
  }
```

### Minimum Reproducible Example

I've created a minimal [Git repo](https://github.com/donalmurtagh/code-coverage-mre) that demonstrates the problem.

1. Clone [the repo](https://github.com/donalmurtagh/code-coverage-mre)
2. Run `yarn install && yarn test:unit:coverage` to generate the coverage report (or use npm instead)
3. Open the file `coverage/lcov-report/index.html` to see the report

If you open the page for `components/toaster-message.vue`, it says 1/2 branches and 2/3 functions are covered, but none of the lines are marked in red (`hideAppMessage` should be red because it's not tested).

If you open the page for `views/login.vue` the lines that are marked in red (uncovered) don't make any sense. There are no tests for this component.

Comment: Have you enabled sourceMaps? It would nice to have demo project with problem

Comment: @maksimr what config do you recommend to enable source maps? I thought they are enabled by default when tests are run

Comment: Shouldn't you be referencing vue-jest like `@vue/vue2-jest@29` when you install? Also have you tried to use just `@vue/vue2-jest` when configuring the transform? Your setup seems slightly different than the [readme](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest).

Comment: @morganney I've tried specifying just `@vue/vue2-jest` in the transform, but it doesn't make any difference. I've looked at the readme and I can't see any significant difference between the setup it recommends and what I'm using, can you?

Comment: If you provide a MRE I'm sure it will get resolved.

Comment: @morganney done - see above

Comment: There is also one [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/500). Are you able to use different versions of Jest?

Comment: @morganney yes, I can change the version of Jest, or any other dependency

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What worked for me was adding [`coverageProvider: 'v8'`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/480#issuecomment-1306821131) to the `jest.config.js`. I'm not entirely sure why changing [`coverageProvider`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coverageprovider-string) works, but seems like `vue-jest` is having [general problems with collecting coverage correctly](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+coverage) due to babel dependency changes.

Try adding this to your Jest configuration:

```js
coverageProvider: 'v8'
```

Then `npm run test:unit:coverage`.

This worked on Node v16.16.0 and v18.12.1.

Comment: It worked, thanks very much! Be sure not to spend all of the bonus on hookers and coke.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I prefer Pepsi.

Comment: Switching to v8 fixed my code coverage issues but now the all html in the <template> tag is being shown as covered as well as the css in the <style> tag. Is this expected behavior? I would think it won't be included since it doesn't contain javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

`jest` uses its own version of Babel to transpile your code, but the source map that generates it could be unnacurate or have a differrent version than the one you are using.

You can make sure that `jest` is using the same version of Babel that you're using in your app by adding the following configuration to your package.json file:

```json
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
  }
}
```

Also, could it be that even though your `package.json` has that version you have something else in the `package-lock.json`?

Comment: I think my current jest configuration is equivalent to your suggestion. I've updated my question to include the jest configuration

Comment: I've created a minimal example that demonstrates the problem - see the update to my post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like solution with `coverageProvider: 'v8'` added by [@morganney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74851858/8770040) works.

For the problem of generating a coverage report.

```
Failed to write coverage reports:
  ERROR: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path\to\file\<<jsx-config-pragma.js>>.html'
```

Just remove the `.ts`(`"\\.(tsx|ts|jsx|js)$"`) files from configuration (package.json)

```json
...
"transform": {
  "\\.(tsx|jsx|js)$": [
    "@swc-node/jest",
    {
      "dynamicImport": true
    }
  ]
},
...
```